# Как взять данные в джанго из html и отправить их на майл?

Tags: html, python, django

Я разобрался с send_email, оно отправляет на почту письмо, но как сделать так, чтобы описание было взято из формы Html?

Вот view.py и я хочу в message взять текст из инпута html
    '''

```
def send_email(request):
   subject = 'Новая заявка!'
   message = 'New message'
   email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
   recipient_list = ['warglok@gmail.com', ]
   send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
   return HttpResponse("Successful")
'''
```

Html код из которого я хочу взять данные

```
   {% csrf_token %}

   <label for="team_name">Введите текст: </label>
   <input id="team_name" type="text" name="name_field" value="Default name for team.">
   <a href="/send" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark col-2">Отправить</a>

</form>
```

Извините за непрофессиональное объяснение, обещаю в будущем исправиться.

---

[image: Такая вот ошибка]

Может я чего-то не понимаю, может где-то есть конфликты в коде

Answer (score 0):

Dсе очень просто. В одну строчку. `request.POST` берет значение с поля формы по атрибуту name

```
  message = request.POST['name_field']
```

Comment: Сделал так как вы и сказали, но появилась ошибка http://dpaste.com/3X2WGQN

Comment: @DobryKisik а можете скинуть полную форму в вопрос с открывающегося тега <form>

Comment: <form method="get" class="form-row">

Comment: @DobryKisik get на post поменяйте

Comment: Я менял, к сожалению не помогло(

Comment: @DobryKisik Что значит "не помогло"?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin такая вот ошибка

TypeError at /send/
'QueryDict' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

**Template**

```
<form method="POST" action="/send">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <label for="team_name">Введите текст: </label>
   <input id="team_name" type="text" name="name_field" value="Default name for team.">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark col-2">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

**views**

```
def send_email(request):
   subject = 'Новая заявка!'
   message = request.POST.get('name_field')
   email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
   recipient_list = ['warglok@gmail.com', ]
   send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
   return HttpResponse("Successful")
```

*P.S. В шаблоне в атрибуте `action` лучше указывайте имя урла.*

Comment: С вашим вариантом заработало, только вот письмо приходит пустое, mesage пустой, не подскажете что сделать?

Comment: Покажите Ваш код во `views`.

Comment: `
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from .models import MyForm
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'extendBase/front_page.html')


def send_email(request):
    subject = 'Новая заявка!'
    message = request.POST.get('name_field')
    email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    recipient_list = ['warglok@gmail.com', ]
    send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
    return HttpResponse("Successful")
`

Comment: Непонятно ничего.

Comment: Не форматируется как следует

Comment: Тогда ничем помочь не смогу. Смотри, почему у тебя None (скорее всего) из формы приходит.